# Is it possible to track time spent on an individual issue in JetBrains YouTrack Cloud?

Tags: cloud, jetbrains-ide, agile, youtrack, time-tracking

I want to track time I've spent on a single issue in my JetBrains YouTrack Cloud in such a way, that I declare work on a specific issue and YouTrack is dealing with time tracking by itself. When I consider issue as done YouTrack stops tracking time and I get value of time spent on the issue.

Is it possible? I've read the documentation and dig deep in the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

For now I only managed to set Estimation and Spent Time fields for issues, but values for both are set manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for functionality similar to the [In Progress Work Timer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/Workflow-Work-Timer.html) workflow. It automatically starts a timer when the issue's State field value is changed to "In progress" and stops when the State becomes "Resolved".

Here you can read how to include workflows to the project: [Attach a Workflow to your Project﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/Manage-Workflows.html#attach-workflow-project).

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my problem for default projects that have In Progress and Fixed issue stages. For e.g. Kanban I started to use [Stopwatch-style Work Timer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/Workflow-Standalone-Work-Timer.html).